# pandas cut left inclusive exclusive bin edges

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is it possible to specify bins with left inclusive and other bins with right inclusive in `pd.cut`?

For example: can I achieve this:
6.5 > Acidic, 6.5 >= neutral <= 7.5,  Alkalic >7.5 ? (notice that neutral is both lef and right inclusive)

sample df:

```
    ph
0   4.0
1   6.5
2   7.0
3   7.5
4   10.0
```

desired result:

```
    ph  ph_category
0   4.0     Acidic
1   6.5     neutral
2   7.0     neutral
3   7.5     neutral
4   10.0    Alkalic
```

I could not find a solution so far, and it seems quite trivial

Comment: please show a sample df and the expected output

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use:

1. Your own category:

   ```
   phCat = pd.Categorical(['Acidic', 'Neutral', 'Alkalic'], ordered=True)
   ```
2. A custom function:

   ```
   def getPhCat(n):
       if n < 6.5:
           return phCat[0]
       elif n > 7.5:
           return phCat[2]
       else:
           return phCat[1]
   ```

Then, to categorize your substances, you can run somenting like:

```
df['Reaction'] = df.pH.apply(getPH)
```

Starting from the following source DataFrame:

```
  Substance    pH
0     Aaaaa   0.0
1     Bbbbb   5.9
2     Ccccc   6.4
3     Ddddd   6.5
4     Eeeee   6.6
5     Fffff   7.0
6     Ggggg   7.5
7     Hhhhh   7.6
8     Iiiii   8.1
9     Jjjjj  14.0
```

I got:

```
  Substance    pH Reaction
0     Aaaaa   0.0   Acidic
1     Bbbbb   5.9   Acidic
2     Ccccc   6.4   Acidic
3     Ddddd   6.5  Neutral
4     Eeeee   6.6  Neutral
5     Fffff   7.0  Neutral
6     Ggggg   7.5  Neutral
7     Hhhhh   7.6  Alkalic
8     Iiiii   8.1  Alkalic
9     Jjjjj  14.0  Alkalic
```

Comment: I've edited my question, before it was only left inclusive, now it has both left and right inclusive.

Comment: Thanks, so my understanding is that this could not be accomplished via `pd.cut`?

Comment: In *pd.cut* you can set **all** bins to be either left-inclusive or right-inclusive. As far as I know, there is no possibility to set inclusiveness of individual bins.

Comment: Indeed. I looked through the documentation, including the documentation for `pd.IntervalIndex`, and mixed left- and right-inclusive is not an option in either. Valdi_Bo's solution is how I have done this in the past.